# How to align a container to the right with Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to have an element aligned to the top right of the window. I wrote this:

```
  <div class="container-fluid fixed-top">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8"><!-- dummy --></div>
      <div class="col-4 alert alert-primary">Here I am!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that if I resize the window, the dummy column give an additional vertical space.

I tried to use `float-right`, but my `div` goes out from its container.

Is there a way just have my `alert alert-primary` have a minimum text-width (let's say 20 chars) and being right aligned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this (**no extra CSS**)...

```
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ml-auto col-auto alert alert-primary">Here I am!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/KeorPCu7AR

The `col-auto` class minimizes the column width to fit its' content, and then `ml-auto` will push it to the right. This way you won't need the dummy column.

***Edit***

Also, it would be better to put the alert *inside* the column...

```
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top p-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ml-auto col-auto">
            <div class="alert alert-primary">Here I am!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Also see: [Right aligned Bootstrap container which also aligns with default container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778466/right-aligned-bootstrap-container-which-also-aligns-with-default-container)

Answer (score 6):

Using `d-flex` and `justify-content-end` on its parent,  you can do so.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div class=" alert alert-primary">Here I am!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

`fixed-top` change position of an element to `fixed` and its top property to `0`. Since the `container` is `fixed` meaning it is removed from the normal flow of the document, you need to  set its `right` position to `0` to move to the right side.

Bootstrap does not have classes for such a purpose. So, you need to use custom `CSS`.

```css
.position-r-0 {
  right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top position-r-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto ml-auto alert alert-primary">Here I am!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There might be some alignment issue. If so, increase the the right position, eg `right: 5rem` or `5px`.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: fixed, and anchor it to the top and right sides of the page:

```
#fixed-div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Yes I can do this, but it is not Bootstrap anymore